# Using iptables to Bridge Network Interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I three devices connected like so;

[image: pictured configuration].

- Device A runs Windows.
- Devices B and C run Linux

I want device A to be able to connect with device C and vice versa. Device B does not need to anything but bridge the connection between the two interfaces. 
All of the IP's are static. I have implimented the following `iptables` solution, however, this solution only allows for connections originating with Device C due to the nature of the `masquerade`. I can currently ping from device C to device A. But from device A I cannot ping any of the IP addresses on the `eth0` interface

I would like to be able to ping both ways from A -> C and from C -> A.

The following code runs on Device B.

```
 sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
 iptables -A FORWARD -i sn0 -o usb0 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A FORWARD -i usb0 -o sn0 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o usb0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question may be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se] or [superuser](http://superuser.com). Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link to request migration there.

Answer (score 1):

iptables isn't used for this sort of functionality, you will get more success creating a network bridging interface on the middle B device.

The Arch wiki has a good guide to setting one up (the guide will apply to most other Linux distros, not just Arch), at [this link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge)